# SSHing into raspberry pi from laptops via direct Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, ethernet, raspberry-pi

Previously, I was able to ssh into my raspberry pi via direct Ethernet connection and WiFi sharing.

I achieved this by accessing `raspberrypi.mshome.net`. However, this now does not work and PUTTY now displays `connection refused`. Are there any fixes to this? I using windows 10 on a laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is sshd running on the raspberry pi process list? It suggests that it does not have one up and running or the machine is not reachable.

does ping  work? if not try adding a dot at end of machine name.

if you have telnet you can verify the port is running and accessible from windows with ..

```
[pete.win10] ➤ telnet raspberryip 22
Trying 192.168.1.114...
Connected to ras.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
```

if you cant find telnet try download MobaXTerm. its fantastic :-)

if it stopped running after reboot its possible its only running but not enabled. in this case try

```
systemctl enable ssh
```

then reboot to make sure it stays active

Comment: Yep, I've checked that ssh is enabled on my pi, but still no joy.

Comment: ok and how about the telnet test does it work or not?. You should also check if the firewall is allowing port 22 to connect on the raspberry pi side. go to Raspberry Pi Configuration app and check interfaces tab for SSH enabled